# Reactjs passing multiple variables into an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am currently replacing markup into reactJs components.

There is an input field that requires two variables

```
<input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value='$userToCall $interviewId' />
```

I am used to adding one variable like this

```
<input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={$userToCall} />
```

would I just add them both like so?

```
<input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={$userToCall $interviewId} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={`${userToCall} ${interviewId}`} />
```

#### Updated

Try

`<input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={userToCall + interviewId} />`

Comment: 13:9  error  '$userToCall' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
  14:9  error  '$interviewId' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Comment: it doesn't use the vars

Comment: -- this has taken hold - but then the value is an object -- <input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={{$userToCall, $interviewId}} />

Comment: NOTE: You need to use the tick ` not ' for String literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You have put double brackets on. This is is making it an object.. NOTE that the { is moving from JSX elements to JavaScript. Therefore {{ is going to javaScript, then into an object literal.

Comment: this is correct -- 
                        <input type='hidden' id='invite-to' value={$userToCall + ' ' + $interviewId} />